# How do i communicate between my LAN & WLAN which are on different subnets?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan

I want to communicate from a PC to a server and vice versa where the PC and server are on completely different subnets.
The configuration is:

Router 1 has an ip address of 172.16.13.1(LAN)
The PC has an ip address assigned by router1's DHCP client.
Router 1 is connected to router2 through a WLAN interface(192.168.1.9)
Router2 has an ip address of 192.168.1.1(LAN), gateway 192.168.1.254

PC<->Router1<->Router2<->Server

How can i communicate/pass traffic from my PC to the server which are on different subnets? I have done some research online but as I am not that familiar with networking, I still dont understand how this can be done. Would i need to implement some static routes?

Thank you

Comment: Hi. What research have you done so far - what do you understand?

Comment: Have you looked at using a VPN?

Comment: Are these 2 networks physically co-located? Do they need to be distinct networks? How are they connected (ethernet cable, wireless, etc)? Is this a home or small business? Much of these could be eliminated by making one big Lan and essentially making router 2 a switch, unless that has other implications.

Comment: I am not that familiar with VPNs, can you establish a VPN over two LAN networks through wifi?

Comment: @acejavelin Yes the 2 networks are physically co-lated and they need to be distinct(on different networks). Router2 has a modem connected to it where as router1 is connected to router2 through wireless

Comment: @Nightflare11 if the two networks cannot be combined, I suggest the port forwarding answer below then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup "port forwarding" on your router that connects the 192.168.0.* subnet to the 172.16.13.* subnet

If you need to connect to multiple PCs you will need to distinguish them by a different ports, since you only have 1 IP available.

It would look like this:

PC1 192.168.1.2:80   -> 172.16.13.1:81
PC2 192.168.1.2:80   -> 172.16.13.1:82
etc.

(assuming 172.16.13.1 is the WLAN interface of your router)

if you type http:// 172.16.13.1:82 yo your browser you end up on the web server of PC2.

Each router has a different setup here is an example for Dlink routers:
[Dlink port forwarding guide](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Dlink/)

Comment: Please see updated details

Comment: @Nightflare11 What details do you need? The ports needed to be forwarded would depend on the services required, such as web on port 80, https on 443, SMTP on 25, etc., and the origins such as a PC on LAN1 or a device outside the network to get to the server. There is no magic way to make a server behind 2 router/firewalls visible to the internet, it will take a lot of setup on both routers.